# no password and system recovery needed and i am thinking of just wiping pc and reinstalling everything

Tags: windows, reinstall, system-restore, password-recovery

My computer password is lost. It also needs system recovery but that requires a password. I have everything i need off this pc can i just wipe the computer and reinstall windows to get my computer back into use.

Comment: Yes... You can...

Answer (score 1):

If your PC has Windows 7 then you can try changing the password.

1. Try going into startup recovery by pressing the Power key when the system is booting then wait until it finishes.
2. Click on "View problem details" - a Notepad file will open up.
3. Go To File -> Open
4. Explorer will open. Navigate to `Windows\System32`
5. Then search for "sethc".
6. Rename it to anything, say "xyz"
7. Find "cmd" and rename it to "sethc"
8. Boot up the PC again.
9. In the login screen, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key five times.

Command Prompt will open up and you can change the password from there.

To change the password from the command prompt: `net user <name> <pass>`. Example: `net user amh2016 abcdef` 
Thanks @Marc.2377

Comment: +1 for hacky methods, (Though using utilman works nicer because that replaces that button at the bottom). Additionally you should tell OP how he can actually change the password, not just how to get a prompt

Comment: The author should format this answer.

Comment: To change the password from the command prompt: `net user <name> <pass>`. Example: `net user amh2016 abcdef` (feel free to incorporate this into your answer).